# Is there a way to automatically discard amended commits in a git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

The following situation is something that happens every once in a while when I am working with Git. I start with a linear history, with two branches. The master currently points at C. Branch A is a branch that I am asking my colleagues to merge into master and branch B has unfinished work that I haven't made public yet.

```
 C
  \ 
   A - B
```

During the code review, my colleague notices that there is a typo in the last commit in branch A. Instead of creating a new commit just to fix the typo, I amend the offending commit and we merge that into master. Master now points to A', which is the commit that corrected the typo.

```
C - A'
 \
   A - B
```

The next step is to rebase the unfinished work. I want the final result to look like this:

```
C - A'
     \
      B
```

However, by default Git assumes that A and A' are completely unrelated commits and it tries to do this instead:

```
C - A'
     \
      A - B
```

Which finally brings us to my question:

Is there a way to ask git to figure out by itself that we don't need to include A in the rebase because A' is already there? Or is this one of those situations that always requires human intervention to remove the duplicate commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved thru `git rebase --skip`.

```
C - A'
     \
      B
```

When the branch B is rebased on master, this would be what you would see -

```
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

You can then do `git rebase --skip` which would skip the commit and the git history would look clean

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do what you're asking, but in these situations I've grown accustomed to always using `git rebase -i`.  This allows you to:

- Remove `A` from the to-do list first.
- Avoid creating an `A'` commit that isn't already an ancestor to `B`.  You instead can commit the typo fix as `D`:

  ```
  C
   \
    A - B - D
  ```

  And then when running `git rebase -i C`, you can reorder the to-do list to make `D` a fixup commit to `A`.  Then you'll end up with:

  ```
  C
   \
    A' - B
  ```

  which is your desired end state. (If you commit `D` via `git commit --fixup A`, then the reordering will happen automatically when running `git rebase -i` if `git.autosquash = true`.)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help if I have two branches, one pointing at  A and one pointing at B. If I rebase one of them then the other one continues pointing at the old version of the history, which will include A instead of A'. (Unless there is a way to rebase both branches at the same time... Is there?)